# Using Custom Option Page Checkbox value in front end

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

So I made new admin page with some settings in it. I have a check box there. How to use it's value to change css in front end of home page? I would like to hide the sidebar if the checkbox is checked.

edit: I am using this tool https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-option-page-generator/

Code: https://pastebin.com/3Pa4jPj0

There is this comment at the bottom:

```
/* 
 * Retrieve this value with:
 * $podesavanja_options = get_option( 'podesavanja_option_name' ); // Array of All Options
 * $hide_sidebar_0 = $podesavanja_options['hide_sidebar_0']; // Hide sidebar
 */
```

But how to use that value on index.php to remove the sidebar?

PS: If I add `var.dump($hide_sidebar_0);` on that option page, it gives me NULL for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I added more info :) I tried alot but even var.dump($hide_sidebar_0) on that option page is giving me NULL value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's hard to provide a concrete answer since you didn't post any code, I can offer some pointers -- you should look into javascript and event listeners. You can bind an event listener to the "change" event of your checkbox, and have that trigger some javascript code to hide the sidebar.